# php get first unique substring

Tags: php, string, substring, unique

how can you get the first unique substring in a given string.

for example i want to find the unique string being asked "**tr6hrvjh**" in

> $string = "htr6hrvjhtr6hrvjhtr6hrvjhtr6hrvjh";

i tried **substr_count** and using **for()**, also tried nested loops. still can't get it work
do you have any method in order to retrieve the unique string? or is it possible to use regex?
i am currently using php. if you can do it in other programming languages please do so.

-- EDIT --

ok. just what **niftydude** said the unique string im referring to is repeated. sorry about that. let me rephrase the question

the first character in $string (h) is used as the 'limiter' for the unique string being searched. it indicates the end of the unique string being searched.

the second character (t) is the start of the unique string. that's why i said "tr6hrvjh"

what i have done is i looped per character in the $string starting from the first offset [1] which is (t). the loop will only end if

- You found the 'limiter' character which is 'h'
- The string already repeated itself for example while you are traversing on the $string you already have 'tr6hrvjh'. after another several loops you detected 'tr6hrvjhtr6' all over again. your loop must end.

the conditions for the 'unique' string are:

- must be alphanumeric only
- must be >= 5
- all characters in the $string must be in that 'unique' string. for example if the $string is **htr6ahrvjhtr6ahrvjhtr6ahrvjh** the unique string must be **tr6ahrvjh** not **tr6ah** which leaves **rvjh** in the $string

note that the $string always looks that way. the first and second character always acts as the last and the first character of the 'unique' string respectively. and the unique string is always repeated in $string, no other characters in between it's repetition.

another problem is that there are two h's in the string being searched. well i hope you understand it. feel free to comment :D

-- EDIT --

test strings i have encountered so far are like the ones i have given to you

> htr6hrvjhtr6hrvjhÔi§¯ŸÍ©¥g§¬Ð™×ªhÖØ¡˜¦ÓkÕ¬šÕª—©«
>
> htr6hrvjhtr6Ôi§¯ŸÍ©¥g§¬Ð™×ªhÖØ¡˜¦ÓkÕ¬šÕª—©«
>
> 512354651235465Ôi§¯ŸÍ©¥g§¬Ð™×ªhÖØ¡˜¦ÓkÕ¬šÕª—©«
>
> 5123546512354651235Ôi§¯ŸÍ©¥g§¬Ð™×ªhÖØ¡˜¦ÓkÕ¬šÕª—©«

Comment: how is `tr6hrvjh` a unique substring? I see them repeated :o

Answer (score 1):

It may be that I still did not understand your question correctly, but try this:

```
function getUniqueString($string) {
  $delimiter = $string[0];
  $chunks = array_filter(explode($delimiter, $string), function ($chunk) {
    return preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/', $chunk);
  });

  return implode(array_unique($chunks)) . $delimiter;
}
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/oYoD40

Comment: you're a god. this may do. though the function cannot work on the current string I am testing on - http://codepad.viper-7.com/jOwfrR

Comment: @kapitanluffy What would be the expected result for that new test case? Until now I thought the unique string would form a repeating pattern (that's the idea behind finding it).

Comment: this one 'tr6rvjh' .i encountered a new string which has shorter repeating pattern than the one I said above. though short it still managed to repeat on the last 3 chars (tr6) before the non-alpha chars

Comment: @kapitanluffy I see, could you add some more test-strings and expected results to the question, makes things a lot easier ;)

Comment: i guess the first one worked better. the preg_match() gave me an idea to retrieve the alphanum chars first then use your older getUniqueString() . where can i see the older version of that? kinda confused w/ codepad

Comment: @kapitanluffy click on the "edited x mins ago", next to my name, below the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Use `strpos()`. Give your string and the 'needle', and it will return the index the first instance of your needle in the string. If it is not found, it will return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

The needle in the haystack example:

```
 $pos = strpos($haystack,$needle);

    if($pos === false) {
     // string needle NOT found in haystack
    }
    else {
     // string needle found in haystack
    }
```

http://www.maxi-pedia.com/string+contains+substring+PHP

Also, the php.net manual on it:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php